# Java Servlet to start & monitor a polling process

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, process-monitoring

I have a Web app that contains a polling process (infinite while loop) that is started up by a Servlet when the Tomcat service starts up.

```
<load-on-startup>0</load-on-startup>
```

Which works fine.

If this were a Unix process then I could check it on the command line using:

```
ps -ef | grep <myProcess>
```

Is there anything (simple) that can be used in a Servlet to monitor the status of my Polling process?

**EDIT**

To clarify, all I really want to see is that the process is still running and hasn't stopped.

Comment: You can execute the command `"ps -ef | grep <myProcess>"` from Java too.

Comment: Make your servlets `doGet` method to return some vital statistics about your worker thread. You might check your threads alive status; or your thread might update some stats every time it awakes.

Comment: Thank you Gyro. I have considered something like this myself and will probably go down this route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO, you should not use a Servlet for that use case, but a ServletContextListener. In its `contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce)`, the listener should :

- start the polling service thread
- put in a ServletContext attribute an object containing state (last operation date, number of operation per ...) from the polling thread (and having a synchronization mechanizme)

Then, the listener could stop the polling thread in its `contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce)`, and any servlet (including JSPs) could get the state of the polling thread from the ServletContext.

Comment: Thanks Serge,
I'm going to look more into this and see what I can find out/come up with. Do you have an example or a link where there is one?

Comment: An upadate - I completed my WebListener code today (Well started it and got it working). Thanks for your help again Serge